# Conditional type based on whether success or error typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to return both errors and success from a function

```
type Result = ResultSuccess | ResultFailure;
interface ResultSuccess {
    success: true,
    response: Interface1
}
interface ResultFailure{
    success: failure,
    error: Interface2
}
```

This works fine, but then in my typescript code

```
// 'responses' is Result[]
const successfulRequests = responses.filter((x) => x.success).map((x) => x.response)
```

Here there's a type error because the `x.response` cannot determine if it's a success or failure (therefore would exist or not), despite checking for the type being 'success: true'

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.filter` does not modify the type of the array without you explicitly asking for it.
You can make you filter function into a type guard to narrow the type:

```
const successfulRequests = responses
  .filter((x): x is ResultSuccess => x.success)
  .map((x) => x.response);
```

This includes the safety net you want of it not blindly using a wrong type:

```
const successfulRequests = responses
  .filter((x): x is number => x.success) // Type Error: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Result'. ts(2677)
  .map((x) => x.response);
```

Answer (score 0):

`responses.filter(x => x.success)` returns type `Result[]`
You have to explicitly tell typescript what type you now have
i.e. do this:

```js
const successfulRequests = (responses.filter(x => x.success) as ResultSuccess[]).map(x.response)
```

Comment: Yeah that's an option, but if an entirely wrong type was returned due to some change then that'd still succeed which could be dangerous.

Comment: Yes of course, but thats the point of your `success` flag, no?
Is your problem the type error or that you want to do runtime validation?

Comment: Type error. If someone changed the return type of the function generating `responses: Result[]` and returned `{ success: true, daliksjhdliasjdioas: {} }` then we'd essentially be typing that to ` success: true, response: []` when it's nothing similar. I just want to inherit whatever the type from `responses` is.

Comment: in your example at runtime you would have `{success: true, response: undefined}` the problem here is that typescript is a language on top of javascript and transpiles down to js. I'm unsure what you mean by inheriting the type of responses. If you want to do type validation then you have to use reflection to get access to types at runtime or do manual verification.

Comment: I don't care what types there are at runtime. I'm just caring about the actual typing of it.

"in your example at runtime you would have {success: true, response: undefined}"

No you wouldn't as undefined cannot be assigned to the response variable unless it's from an outside source (because typing, and that should be validated there)